# Reverse SSH Tunnel or TCP tunnel using the Remote Desktop Services API

Tags: c#, ssh, reverse, rdp

I'm making an application that will allow for bidirectional desktop control for my own learning process, I don't like when standard RDP sessions lock the endpoints computer when a RDP session is in progress.

**The setup is as follows:**

- SSH Server at home
- Computer A at home.
- Computer B at client endpoint.

The problem is that I cannot establish a connection with the connection string provided through the RDP API. I have attempted NAT UPNP port forwarding but I have ruled this out as a solution.

My current avenue of interest is to create a reverse ssh tunnel, and to have machine B tunnel into the ssh server, from that point Computer A will run:
ssh -l 3389:127.0.0.1:3389 credentials <-- Currently I'm doing this through putty. (Will use a ssh library to do this automatically)

Secondly it might also be possible to establish a connection via TCP:

Client B -> connects to Client A (Or the server links them and routes data)
Client B Generates RDP string 
Client B Sends RDP string to client A
Client A attempts to connect to client Bs active RDP session.
..Here I hit a wall. Since the connection string generated points to one publicly routable address (IPv6) and the rest are temp IPv6 Addresses and the private IPv4 Address and the Link-Local address.

Computer B will then reverse tunnel into the ssh server:

ssh -R 6000:127.0.0.1:3389 credentials <-- Also through putty for testing.

This works if I were to open the built in remote desktop application and target

localhost:6000

but I want the client (computer B) to generate a connection string and send it via TCP (I can handle this internally, but have been just copy pasting the connection string manually. Still just for testing.)

Here is the connection string broken down into its tags:

```
<E>
        <A KH="QHltZY9ISIdaMb3DNLVCVL8z22Q="

            KH2="sha256:cEv4C57cmofFr8bJsttCX+taX5sWxWmgvSjpWRpTZ8U="

            CE= 
                "MIIC4jCCAcqgAwIBAgIQSbu3zINwkqBB78x2uwORijANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAa&#xA;               MRgwFgYDVQQDEw9QcmltYXJ5LURlc2t0b3AwHhcNMTgwNjA4MDY1MDU1WhcNMTgx&#xA;
                 MjA4MDY1MDU1WjAaMRgwFgYDVQQDEw9QcmltYXJ5LURlc2t0b3AwggEiMA0GCSqG&#xA;
                 SIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDQ4tSRTPnCJuhCEJoOY8veHaFNg02Zmlg+&#xA;
                 3eXZCH65Rejxlk1cmARknhw5+MuXTvka+oApQeWtZQBTpoE/KD1vaHOnQS0yLc8P&#xA;
                 g6BvekNcoOY+6U9zOc1dP+EignJ8dHkSYc8Jr+k/OCfDTFoQZ/HVRUKHwd1ScNa2&#xA;
                 YczGSrhboCevbSQxSTtcsI7H4tL6d58fdlp+lPXkLCkzo29IQCqKT5q94geXLvDa&#xA;
                 t/U2rK6OcRFycEoNrwNPy7bwAnfIRTFDrLiQ8/6b28DrpPM7cJyM+K6cqsIOkkAd&#xA;
                 gXPJNNMMKT3ej1KDTZ+UiLq3c9plPP7SUm9xLx7rhEct+zTf8RUhAgMBAAGjJDAi&#xA;
                 MBMGA1UdJQQMMAoGCCsGAQUFBwMBMAsGA1UdDwQEAwIEMDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF&#xA;
                 AAOCAQEApU2ec3ZgWDHQ4/gsXv/wlpLeIMbeIpZrf9NpgqV6Ig3SR8PMldEgfGfz&#xA;
                 XpB6C8mdoqCQglVWijr7M/QvZ9emrwNkfEDiKFuUHUETvdSD48jPJEwGtphhM58e&#xA;
                 07O+y8VP5vrOn0uR/VTKx8M9OMBehDhu9SC1H3/NGqRfbGDleCbTz1KvAFKOJrCH&#xA;
                 EvDHB+hyUFlapW/q/ZIMOefaYFYv/vnZvI6Sfy/NDKkSaOR0RBjrRA2dbmj6D0YU&#xA;
                 EuU1FYwqmTtW8jlmoz2WfaLEli8QLkGx6lw1ej891g5AvvdD1UWVAUfssIlMl1YL&#xA;
                 NSp6g8qJJrKtQvlCVUxwG4IH4ufb9w=="

                 ID="secretusername"
        />

         <C>
         <T ID="1" SID="0">
             <L P="55114" N="fe80::710b:8671:823c:7aab%17"/>
             <L P="55115" N="2604:282:3900:8eb0::af33"/>
             <L P="55117"N="2604:282:3900:8eb0:710b:8779:28c3:7aab"/>
             <L P="55117" N="2604:282:3900:8eb0:5dc5:b08e:de21:8bb8"/>
             <L P="55118" N="10.0.0.14"/>
        </T>
     </C>
 </E>
```

*It may be important to note that many of the addresses listed between the < T > tag are redundant*

My question is mainly: Is there a way that I can generate a connection string that will support reverse ssh or allow TCP to reroute data and provide an address that is publicly accessible, or is there a way I could append my own tag to the connection string:  that would allow the connection to work.

The application works on local networks without error. I have searched for answers on the specific question that I am trying to solve any advice is appreciated, thank you.

**TLDR**

Machine A:
ssh -L 3389:127.0.0.1:3389 credentials
Machine B:
ssh -R 6000:127.0.0.1:3389 credentials
SSHD:
 Connects the two tunnels

Machine A: Built in windows utility can target localhost:6000 and remotely connect to machine B.

Problems: don't want to use built in utility.

Cannot connect remotely using the connection string generated by machine B. As it only points to the local address of the device.

So, how can I generate a connection string that supports a publicly routable address, without having the port forward.

Comment: Make a 2nd tcp connection.  RDP is secure and you cannot send a message using RDP until the connection is completed and you need the connection string to complete.  So use a non-secure connection to send with a different port number.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think I understand what you are saying, but could you elaborate more? How may I connect to a remote endpoint listening for an RDP connection (via a client running on their machine) through TCP. 
Endpoint connects to me via TCP (Where I use the connection string that--that endpoint has generated), then with that connection I establish a connection to them or I just transmit data through that "channel" that they've established with me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I did not say use RDP!!!  The RDP is secure communications for interface with the unix shell.  I siad to use TCP with no encryption. On PC B open a TCP listener before starting RDP.  Then on computer A when a RDP connection opens connect to A on TCP and send back the connection string.

Comment: Alright, you are saying once this process has been completed it will allow for a RDP connection to be established, even though the RDP string that is generated only provides the IPv6 address (and some temp IPv6 addresses) as well as the link local and the local IPv4 Address. Again, thanks.

Comment: I really don't know how you code is organized or if you are using IPv4 or IPv6.  The IP version should matter since the Net TCP can handle both IPv4 and IPv6.  I'm just saying the RDP is secure and you need to get the connection string using an un-secure connection.

Comment: This won't show you the layout of my code, but this may show you how my application works. All I want to do is generate a connection string that has a **public** IPv4 Address, the connection string shown in the example is generally what is generated which doesn't allow for remote connection.
https://imgur.com/lBAoqiC This application can host a RDP session and connect to RDP sessions provided the RDP connection string.

Comment: Remove the C# tag? This appears to be about ssh tunneling only.

Comment: I haven't included any code in C#, however I was looking for a solution in C#.I haven't found a solution to this problem yet, as it would appear that RDP requires UPNP to be enabled on the router, I would like a variant that uses UDP or TCP, that could be used in WPF over Windows Forms in C#.